# Why would $.browser be undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I am using a JQuery file < 1.9.1 and $.browser when utilized is showing undefined. When I call $ in the console I get:

```
function (e,t){return new b.fn.init(e,t,r)}
```

My header linking looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="mobile.js"></script>
```

Inside of my mobile.js looks like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
console.log('works');   
});
```

Now when I put $.browser or jQuery.browser in the Google Chrome console window I always get undefined. Do you know why this would happen? Any solutions?

Comment: `$.browser` was deprecated in 1.3 . Don't use it. If you need to, fetch the migration library.

Comment: Because its undefined?

Comment: "JQuery file < 1.9.1" — Less than 1.9.1 covers a range of sins. Precisely which version are you using?

Comment: The solution, as described in the jQuery docs, is to use feature detection instead.

Answer (score 2):

[jQuery.browser() was removed](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-browser-removed).

Comment: " I am using a JQuery file < 1.9.1 "

Comment: I am using a version that is not 1.9.1 but is older.

Comment: @user1618602 1.9 is older than 1.9.1 . Please specify your exact version.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a link to the release notes. 
http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-browser-removed

Comment: " I am using a JQuery file < 1.9.1 "

Comment: The jQuery.browser() method has been deprecated since jQuery 1.3 and is removed in 1.9. If needed, it is available as part of the jQuery Migrate plugin. We recommend using feature detection with a library such as Modernizr.

Comment: This means it is also gone from EVERY VERSION AFTER 1.9.0.0 +++  Including 1.9.1..  it is gone man... interface broken, method depricated..  no longer supported..

Comment: I am using a version that is not 1.9.1 but is older.

Comment: @user1618602 1.9 is older than 1.9.1 . Please specify your exact version.

Answer (score 1):

This was removed on JQuery 1.9 version

Comment: " I am using a JQuery file < 1.9.1 "

Comment: 1.9 is less than 1.9.1 (even if only by a little bit)

Comment: I am using a version that is not 1.9.1 but is older.

Comment: @user1618602 1.9 is older than 1.9.1 . Please specify your exact version.